# Facebook insights API goes only week back

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

I am trying to do some advanced analytics over my FB page, but recently I have encountered a problem. When I try to get some data (lets say "page_views_by_referers_logged_in_unique") I am not able to request for longer period than one week. Api says that valid values for period field are `day, week, days_28, month, lifetime, total_over_range`but for period longer than week it returns only empty array. Can someone tell me what is the problem here? Page is like 2 years old, so I am sure there is enough data for longer periods.

Comment: AFAIK, availability of insights data does not depend on page age only, the number of fans is also important. You need a certain minimum to get data, otherwise you could potentially link certain values back directly to individual user accounts.